# How to access interfaces and types defined in a module

Tags: typescript, module, global

I have a global.d.ts file in the root folder of a project that I'm using between two other projects. The file looks something like this.

```
declare module 'component-interfaces' {
    export type Size = 1 | 2 | 3;
}
```

I try to access this type from the other projects like this:

```
import * as m from 'component-interfaces';
```

I'm getting an error `Cannot find module 'component-interfaces'`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file containing your declaration (`global.d.ts`):

1. does not have any top-level import/export statements
2. is included in your project.

For a file to be included in a project means it's listed in your `tsconfig.json` under the `include` or `files` field. For example, if your declaration is located in `./global.d.ts`, your `tsconfig.json` could include it like this:

```
{
  /* ... */,
  "include": [
    "src",
    "global.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I added `"include": [ "**/*" ]` to the tsconfig.json. However I still get the same error `cannot find module`.